# How to put cursor data in array?

Tags: java, android

I am fetching data from database and after that assigning it to arrays in this process i always get length of all arrays as 1 only.

**Method :**

```
public void fetchData() {

    database.open();
    Cursor cursor = database.getAllData();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (!(cursor.isAfterLast())) {
        nameArr = new String[] { cursor.getString(1) }; // i tried to put cursor data in arr from here
        addressArr = new String[] { cursor.getString(2) };
        contactArr = new String[]{ cursor.getString(3) };
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    database.close();
    Log.d("ArrayLength", Integer.toString(nameArr.length));//The arraylength is 1 i dont know why??

}
```

Comment: You're creating a new String array with only one element each time through the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Cursor.getCount()` outside while loop to initialize all arrays as:

```
 int count=cursor.getCount();
 nameArr=new String[count];
 addressArr=new String[count];
 contactArr=new String[count];
 int index_count=0;
while(!(cursor.isAfterLast())){
    nameArr[index_count]=cursor.getString(1); 
    addressArr[index_count]=cursor.getString(2);
    contactArr[index_count]=cursor.getString(3);
    index_count++;
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

To avoid use of `index_count` use ArrayList to store all data from cursor/

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example...

```
    Cursor client = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    String[][] clients = new String[2][client.getCount()];
    if(client.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            clients[0][i] = client.getString(client.getColumnIndex(CLIENT_NAME));
            clients[1][i++] = String.valueOf(client.getInt(client.getColumnIndex(CLIENT_ID)));
        }while (client.moveToNext());
    }
    client.close();
```